# Optimizing multicriteria filtering for data with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter data with Pandas using a list of values which are a couple of str `book_tittle` and int `book_price` :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# settings_#############################################################################

isbn = {'9782756002484', '9782756025117', '9782756072449'}
url = 'https://www.abebooks.fr/servlet/SearchResults?sts=t&cm_sp=SearchF-_-NullResults-_-Results&isbn={}'
book_title = ["Mondes", "X-Wing"]
book_price = [100, 10]

#######################################################################################

### creation de lien à partir des codes ISBN#
def url_isbn(isbn):
    merged = []
    for link in isbn:
        link_isbn = url.format(link)
        merged.append(link_isbn)
    return merged

### scraping each url from url_isbn
def get_data():
    data = []
    for i in url_isbn(isbn):
        r = requests.get(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        item = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'result-data col-xs-9 cf'})
        for x in item:
            title = x.find('h2', {'class': 'title'}).text.replace('\n', '')
            price = x.find('p', {'class': 'item-price'}).text.replace('EUR ', '').replace(',', '.')
            url = 'https://www.abebooks.fr'+x.find('a', {'itemprop': 'url'})['href']

            products = title, int(float(price)), url
            data.append(products)
    return data
###creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(get_data(), columns=["Titre", "Prix", "URL"])

###Filter data into the dataframe
for filtered in df:
    df_final_to_email = filtered[(df['Titre'].str.contains(book_title) & (df.Prix < book_price))]
    print(df_final_to_email)
```

I'm getting an error : `TypeError : unhashable type : 'list'`

I assume I cannot use a list for filtering in cause of the mix of data type, I tested with Tuple and dict, I get the same kind of error

I also try with `df.query` but it gives empty data frame

The filter will allow me to filter all the books which has "Mondes" in the title for a price < 100 but also all the books which contains "X-Wing" below a price of < 10, I'll also add more item to find with a price related.

| Titre | Prix |
| --- | --- |
| Mondes Infernaux | 95,10 |
| Star Wars, Mondes Infernaux | 75,50 |
| X-Wing Rogue | 9,50 |
| X-Wing Rogue Squadron | 7,50 |

---

Nothing about the filtering, but do you know how I could figure the following :`products = title, int(float(price)), url` ? I had to use `float` as I'm not able to convert like `int(price)` as int, I'm a bit annoyed of having rounded down numbers in the dataframe. (if any moderator can tell me if I have to do another post for this specific need  ? thank you)

Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error resides in your filtering code:

```py
df_final_to_email = filtered[(df['Titre'].str.contains(book_title) & (df.Prix < book_price))]
```

`book_title` is a list. `.str.contains` does not work with list. It works with a single string or a regex pattern.

---

If your intention is to find books with "Mondes" in the title and price under 100 *or* "X-Wing" in the title and price under 10, you can use the following filtering code:

```py
###Filter data into the dataframe
cond = pd.Series([False] * len(df), index=df.index)
for title, price in zip(book_title, book_price):
    cond |= df["Titre"].str.contains(title) & df["Prix"].lt(price)

print(df[cond])
```

How it works:

1. We start by selecting no rows `cond = <all False>`
2. For each `title` and `price`, evaluate each row to see if they meet the criteria. A row needs to only match one `(title, price)` condition from the list so we use the "in-place `or`" operator (`|=`) to update our selection list.

The `|=` operator is equivalent to:

```py
cond = cond | (df["Titre"].str.contains(title) & df["Prix"].lt(price))
```

Comment: woo perfect, I would have never find it, do you mind explain to me the code please :) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need all matching rows in the dataframe there's no need to use a `for` loop.

Maybe try something like this:

```
def find_book(str, price):
    return df[ (df['Titre'].str.contains(str)) & (df['Prix']<price) ]

# find all books containing the substring 'Wing' in the title with price <7
find_book('Wing', 7)
```

Comment: Thank but I need to meet the list in `book_title` and `book_price` :) , I did `find_book(book_title, book_price` but I get the error `TypeError : unhashable type : 'list'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this piece of code filters dataframe as you want (not tested):

```
df_final_to_email = pd.concat([df.loc[df["Titre"].str.contains(t) & df["Prix"].lt(p)] 
                               for t,p in zip(book_title, book_price)])
```